# How to average a List<Mat> in javacv without causing an overflow?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have a bunch of frames from FFMpegGrabber, and am trying to write a method that looks like:

```
private static Mat getAverage(List<Mat> mats) {
    if (mats.size() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("no mats");
    }
    Mat first = mats.get(0);
    Size s = first.size();
    Mat total = new Mat(s);
    MatExpr expr = new MatExpr(total);
    for (Mat m : mats) {
        expr = opencv_core.add(m, expr);
    }
    return opencv_core.multiply(expr, 1/mats.size()).asMat()
}
```

But this seems like it's overflowing since the output matrix does not look like an average at all. I was wondering if anyone knows a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
return opencv_core.multiply(expr, 1/mats.size()).asMat()
```

It should read

```
return opencv_core.multiply(expr, 1.0/mats.size()).asMat()
```

The integer division was just causing everything to go to 0.